# Processing - implement a first person camera?

Tags: 3d, camera, processing

First off, I'm sorry if there are duplicates of this. I did an extensive Google search but was unable to find anything that made sense to me. (I am new to 3D rendering and such.)

I want to make a first person camera that the user can control with the mouse. My current implmentation in Processing looks like this:

```
PMatrix3D cam;
int oldMouseX=0, oldMouseY=0;
void setup(){
    // ...
    cam = new PMatrix3D();
}
void draw(){
    // ...
    int deltaX=oldMouseX-mouseX;
    int deltaY=oldMouseY-mouseY;
    oldMouseX=mouseX;
    oldMouseY=mouseY;
    cam.rotateY((PI/600)*deltaX);
    cam.rotateX((PI/600)*deltaY);
    PVector x = cam.mult(new PVector(1, 0, 0), new PVector(0, 0, 0));
    PVector y = cam.mult(new PVector(0, 1, 0), new PVector(0, 0, 0));
    PVector d = x.cross(y); d.normalize(); d.mult(R);
    float fov = PI/3.0;
    float cameraZ = (height/2.0) / tan(fov/2.0);
    perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), cameraZ/10.0, cameraZ*1000.0);
    camera(0, 0, 0, d.x, d.y, d.z, y.x, y.y, y.z);
    // render objects
}
```

It works well, but there is a problem. When the mouse is moved along the x-axis of the screen, and then the y-axis, or in some way one axis at a time, the camera rolls. I understand that 3D rotation is supposed to work like that, 2 consecutive rotations around 2 axes make a rotation around the third. The problem is that once the camera is in this rolled state, it is difficult to get it to be straight again.

How can I make it so it is easy to point the camera in any direction?
Please explain in easy to understand terms, if possible.

Also, I am a bit confused on

```
cam.rotateY((PI/600)*deltaX);
cam.rotateX((PI/600)*deltaY);
```

Before, I had it as

```
cam.rotateX((PI/600)*deltaX);
cam.rotateY((PI/600)*deltaY);
```

But that cause the x and y axes to be switched. (i.e., moving the mouse horizontally caused the camera to rotate vertically.) Why is this?

Comment: Judging by the amount of new posts on Stack Overflow, I think a lot of people have time on their hands to code during Christmas. Especially non Christians.

Comment: Well, "Happy Holidays" then :P

Comment: [peasycam](http://mrfeinberg.com/peasycam/) is a library for that... If you like :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. But in the meantime can you explain how this is supposed to work?

Comment: it seems you are having a gimbal lock, but I am not 100% sure from your description. Maybe you need to check this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/how-to-rotate-an-object-around-world-aligned-axes/67282#67282

Answer (score 1):

You can use just [the `camera()` method](https://www.processing.org/reference/camera_.html) to change the perspective more easily.

To use it, you probably want two variables: `rotationAngle` and `elevationAngle`. Moving the mouse sideways changes `rotationAngle` between `0` and `TWO_PI`. You can then set variable `centerY` to `sin(rotationAngle)` and `centerX` to `cos(rotationAngle)`. Moving the mouse up and down would change `elevationAngle` to anywhere between `0` and `PI`. Multiply `centerX` and `centerY` by `sin(elevationAngle)` and set `centerZ` to `-cos(elevationAngle)`. You can then call `camera()` with the calculated values.

Final code:

```
float rotationAngle;
float elevationAngle;

float centerX;
float centerY;
float centerZ;

void setup() {
  // ...
}

void draw() {
  // ...
  updateCamera();
  // render objects
}

void updateCamera() {
  rotationAngle = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI);
  elevationAngle = map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, PI);

  centerX = cos(rotationAngle) * sin(elevationAngle);
  centerY = sin(rotationAngle) * sin(elevationAngle);
  centerZ = -cos(elevationAngle);

  camera(0, 0, 0, centerX, centerY, centerZ, 0, 0, 1);
}
```