# How can obtain the relative orientation between two quaternions?

Tags: rotation, quaternion

How do I obtain the relative orientation given two orientations (represented by quaternions `q0` and `q1`)?

Comment: not sure what you are asking here, since you are not telling how did you calculate the quaternion in the first place. but my answer here might be related http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/how-to-rotate-an-object-around-world-aligned-axes/67282#67282 and btw you are mixing euler angles with quaternions which is sth I also addressed in the answer.

Comment: which API are you using? it is supposed to be stated in the documentation of how do you interpret orientation.

Comment: from what I understand you can't extract euler angles in the traditional sense. Try converting the quaternion to a matrix and there is a way of analyzing that matrix to extract the euler angles which may not work. But TBH I feel you are asking the wrong question. why do you want to extract pitch in the first place ?

Answer (score 4):

The relative orientation is obtained simply by division:

```
q = q0 / q1
```

Or, if division is not available:

```
q = q0 * inverse(q1)
```

Note that since the quaternions used to represent rotations are unit quaternions, the inverse of `q1` is simply its [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Unit_quaternion) `q1*`, and is obtained by flipping the sign of `x`, `y`, `z` but not `w`.

Comment: if you checked the edits, he is already doing that `q = q0 * inverse(q1)`, so am not particularly sure what he is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Quaternion is another representation of axis angle. The solution is to create a new quaternion from the original quaternion that only has the needed components.

An axis angle representation can be converted to a quaternion using the following formula

```
q[0] = cos(R/2);
q[1] = sin(R/2)*x;
q[2] = sin(R/2)*y;
q[3] = sin(R/2)*z;
```

Where `R` is the angle in radians, and `(x,y,z)` represents the axis, and quaternion is (R,x,y,z).

So in order to create a new quaternion with only the pitch component you just zero out the other components and normalize the quaternion:

```
Quaternion q; // this is your original quaternion
q.x = 0.0;
q.z = 0.0;
q.Normalize();
```

Edit based on your update:

Sensors AFAIK calculate orientation relative to gravity, in other words Y (or Z) is the direction of the gravity. You need take that into consideration. And I think you don't need to multiply it with the inverse *initial* orientation.

Comment: This works great if I know that the motion is pitch. In general, that is unknown.

Comment: @ilp well, what you can do, is extract the component with the highest contribution to the rotation and use that. So instead of taking a fixed axis. Use the one with the highest contribution and zero out the others.

Comment: @ilp at this point I can't answer your question, because I don't know the neccessary details :-) maybe you should edit the question and give it a context so we are able to help.

Comment: @ilp edited the answer.