# Strange quaternion rotation

Tags: c++, directx, rotation, quaternion

I was implementing some quaternion rotations in too my infant 3d game engine and the rotations were really strange? Excuses my cluelessness.

Anyways this is what I have:

```
static XMVECTOR XMConvertToQuaternion(XMFLOAT3 axis, float radian)
{
    axis = XMNormalize3(axis);
    XMVECTOR tempAxis = XMVectorSet(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z, 1);
    XMVECTOR q = XMQuaternionRotationAxis(tempAxis, radian);
    return q;
}
```

Then later on down when I apply the quaternion to the world matrix I have:

```
XMMATRIX scaling = XMMatrixScaling(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
XMMATRIX rotateX = XMMatrixRotationX(radianRotation.x);
XMMATRIX rotateY = XMMatrixRotationY(radianRotation.y);
XMMATRIX rotateZ = XMMatrixRotationZ(radianRotation.z);

XMMATRIX rotateQX = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(MathHelper::XMConvertToQuaternion(axis, radianRotation.x));
XMMATRIX rotateQY = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(MathHelper::XMConvertToQuaternion(axis, radianRotation.y));
XMMATRIX rotateQZ = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(MathHelper::XMConvertToQuaternion(axis, radianRotation.z));
XMMATRIX translate = XMMatrixTranslation(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mWorld, scaling*rotateQX*rotateQY*rotateQZ*translate);
```

I did get a rotation. However, the character is rotating very strangely.

Comment: Check my answer here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/how-to-rotate-an-object-around-world-aligned-axes/67282#67282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to create your Quaternion rotations matrices (I assume from euler angles) look funny, I would expect you use unit vectors of each axis rather than `axis`

```
XMMATRIX rotateQX = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(MathHelper::XMConvertToQuaternion(XMFLOAT3(1, 0, 0), radianRotation.x));
XMMATRIX rotateQY = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(MathHelper::XMConvertToQuaternion(XMFLOAT3(0, 1, 0), radianRotation.y));
XMMATRIX rotateQZ = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(MathHelper::XMConvertToQuaternion(XMFLOAT3(0, 0, 1), radianRotation.z));
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mWorld, scaling*rotateQX*rotateQY*rotateQZ*translate);
```

does changing the order to:

```
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mWorld, translate*rotateQX*rotateQY*rotateQZ*scaling);
```

make a difference? If you meant to rotate about the origin then translate outwards then you need to be careful with your ordering, though I'm making assumptions about the XM library.

Comment: No, that just made it worse. Haha

Comment: Try taking out the translation and scaling completely. Then test each axis separately if necessary. Results?

Comment: I just got the same results. Must be how I got the quaternion.

Comment: I don't know if you just copied your code wrong, but you are currently using the same axis for each quaternion rotation, which is not what you want to do.